# Static variables being shared between parent and child classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I encountered a bug in my code that turned me crazy for a bit. Essentially I have a parent class that instantiates a static variable, and a Child class that instantiates the same static variable, differently. This should be fine, because `Parent.variable` should be != to `Child.variable`. Well depends in what order you instantiate them.

```
i = 0

class Parent():
    
    _value = None
    
    @classmethod
    def get_value(cls):
        if cls._value is None:
            global i
            i += 1
            cls._value = i
        
        return cls._value


class Child(Parent):
    pass
```

Run:

```
print("Child: ", Child.get_value())
print("Parent: ", Parent.get_value())
```

Output:

> Child:  1
>
> Parent:  2

Run:

```
print("Parent: ", Parent.get_value())
print("Child: ", Child.get_value())
```

Output:

> Parent:  1
>
> Child:  1

See below:

[image]

Is this wanted behavior?

Comment: "This should be fine, because Parent.variable should be != to Child.variable" No?

Comment: This is just basic inheritance, for an class, `cls`, if you do `cls.value`, it checks its own namespace (the class namespace) if the class namespace does not contain the attribute, it checks *all of the classes in the method resolution order*. If it finds the attribute, it returns it, if it doesnt, and `AttributeError` is raised. What you are seeing is the normal behavior.

Comment: in the first case the cls._value is set on the child then the 2nd call does not see it for parent and it runs the increment code again.  in 2nd case it sets it up in the base and then when called for child it can see it in the hierarchy and returns the value.  watch the flow with the debugger and check the attributes show, etc. will help explain that.

Comment: If you want each class's value to be entirely independent, you should give `Child` its own `_value = None` line - that way, `Child`'s value is *never* found via inheritance from `Parent`.

Comment: @jasonharper yeah, that's the solution I thought, but whats the point of inheritance if I have to explicitly define each attribute?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga as commented in the answer below, I think this doesn't make sense. Classes should be created deterministically, and the Child class shouldn't inherit the static attribute of a parent that was set during some runtime code execution

Comment: @Alexis see my response in the answer I gave below.    You are dealing with a dynamic language,  it will have runtime dynamic behaviors that you will need to adjust your thinking for.

Comment: @Alexis it is **100% deterministic**. And *all attributes in Python are set during runtime code execution*. A class definition isn't a declaration, Python *doesn't have declarations*. It is an executable piece of code, exactly equivalent to `mylist = list()`. You can think of it as syntactic sugar to a call to `MyClass = type("MyClass", (object,), {namspace})`. Or else, when do you believe they are set? You are fundamentally misunderstanding the nature of Python.

Comment: @Alexis you *don't* have to explicitly define each attribute. The point if inheritance is the behavior you are seeing. You want to *prevent* inheritance.

Comment: You keep using this word "should" when I think you mean "is how it works in some other language I am familiar with".

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the cls._value is set on the child then the 2nd call does not see it for parent and it runs the increment code again.

In 2nd case it sets it up in the base and then when called for child it can see it in the hierarchy and returns the value.

Watch the flow with the debugger and check the attributes show, etc. will help explain that.

Comment: I understand what is happening, but it doesn't make sense. Classes should be created deterministically, and the Child class shouldn't inherit the static attribute of a parent that was set during some runtime code execution.

Comment: You are using a dynamic language.   There are rules it follows and following THOSE rules the result makes sense.   I think you may be bothered by this because of other languages that you have experienced in your past.   It is different.   I have used C++ and Java and they both have their unique behaviors when it comes to managing visibility and such with inheritance.